# Cutting the String from an input after a certain value with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string, input

I am trying to get a value from an input (type = text) and with ngChange I want to write a function so that a link  like

https://www.youtube.com/user/testbecomes only  user/test

or twitter.com/SomeOne ---> Someone

How am I suppose to do that? I tried substring method but It didnt work fine for me

update : it worked with following code

```
$scope.cutString = function (link){
    var s = link;
    s = s.substring(s.indexOf("/")+1,s.length);
    console.log(s);
    this.link = s;
    $scope.publisher.facebook = s ;
};
```

HTML Part ;

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="facebook" data-ng-model="publisher.facebook"
                   ng-change="cutString(publisher.facebook)">
```

but now the problem is I have the same for Facebook, Twitter and Youtube, how can I manage them all in one method?

PS: I cant upload whole code since its against my work contract.

Comment: So you want to only get the text after the first "/"?

Comment: Please show the code that you've tried.

Comment: @tiagodws and Mike I edited the question again

Comment: @AtlasOkyanus you can post more code and then just make some minor changes to cover for the contract part. In reality, they are not going to care

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could:

```
function getUserPath(link) {
    var regex = /^((http[s]?|ftp):\/)?\/?([^:\/s]+)\//;
    return link.replace(regex, "");
}
```

And then call `getUserPath` wherever you need that logic.

With this RegExp you will always get the path after the first "/" that is not part of the "http://".